# How to get static HTML from haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make some simple graphics applications in Haskell with the [blank-canvas](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blank-canvas) package, and I want to be able to upload these applications on itch.io. However, I don't know how as there are no .html files in the application, just Haskell files. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

There are static html and JavaScript files in the GitHub for `blank-canvas`, but I have no idea how to use them, or even if those are what I'm supposed to use.

Comment: It might help if you give some example of a simple grahic that you want to upload to itch.io.

Comment: A program like the tic-tac-toe example in the blank-canvas GitHub page would be a pretty good example: https://github.com/ku-fpg/blank-canvas/tree/master/examples/tictactoe

Comment: There are no static HTML or JS sites for you to upload. `blank-canvas` starts a Webserver, and what’s executing is your Haskell code. It’s not built to be a static site generator.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I don't know this package and have never used it. But I've used `cabal` a bunch.) From the top level directory, you can build the examples like this:

```
cabal build blank-canvas-example-tictactoe
```

(You can see the list of available executable names [here](https://github.com/ku-fpg/blank-canvas/blob/master/examples/blank-canvas-examples.cabal).) This creates an executable named `blank-canvas-example-tictactoe`... somewhere. The details are a bit involved, but you can ask `cabal` where it put the thing with

```
cabal list-bin blank-canvas-example-tictactoe
```

Presumably you could then upload that executable to itch.io, though you may want to do a bit of testing to see whether there's some other things you're expected to bundle with it -- e.g. dynamically-linked libraries or resource files like jquery or whatever.

Comment: I have an executable that opens a localhost with the HTML stuff I would expect. I want the actual HTML file and/or JavaScript files, so I can make it run within itch.io without requiring a download.

Comment: @lonelyfloat That's probably not possible unless you're willing to put in rather a lot of work.